# Spring mvc form submission bindingresult throws error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web-applications

So my bindingresult throws an error but I'm not able to see it for some reason and I'm not able to figure out what the problem is. I'm guessing the problem lies with the variable targetDate where there is a problem the type. I've pasted my controller and JSP code below. Any help is appreciated!

```
@Controller
public class ToDoController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ToDoService service;
    
    // All date parameters displayed as mm/DD/yyyy
    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/DD/yyyy");
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
                dateFormat, false));
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list-todo", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    // HttpSession allows access to the session
    public String showToDo(ModelMap model,  HttpSession httpSession) {
        String user = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("name");
        model.addAttribute("todos", service.retrieveTodos(user));
        return "list-todos";
    }
    
    // redirect to update form
    @RequestMapping(value = "/update-todo", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUpdateForm(ModelMap model, @RequestParam int id) {
    
        System.out.println("ID " + id);
        // To work with command bean
        model.addAttribute("id", id);
        model.addAttribute("todo", service.retrieveTodo(id-1));
        return "updateToDo";
    }
    
    // What does Valid do?
    @RequestMapping(value = "/update-todo", method= RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String submitUpdate(ModelMap model, @Valid ToDo todo, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("ERROR" + result.getAllErrors());
            // Redirect and pass on the id value
            return "redirect:/update-todo?id=" + todo.getId();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Update todo" + todo);
        service.updateToDo(todo);
        model.clear();
        return "redirect:/list-todo";
    }
    
    // Will be executed first
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add-todo", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAddForm(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("todo", new ToDo());
        return "addToDo";
    }
    
    
    /*
     * Will be executed after form is submitted
     * @Valid ToDo - command bean from addToDo.jsp. 
     * @Valid to validate the information
     * @BindingResult showcases the result of the validation
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add-todo", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitAddForm(ModelMap model , @Valid ToDo todo,  HttpSession httpSession, BindingResult result) {
        System.out.println("running" + result);
        // If there is validation error , return to addToDos page for user to fix the error
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "redirect:/showAddForm?id=?" + todo.getId();
        }
        String user = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("name");
        
        service.addTodo(user, todo.getDescription(), todo.getTargetDate(), false);      
        // Clears the url e.g. name?=jyj123
        model.clear();
        // return to the url which executes the showToDO
        return "redirect:/list-todo";
    }
    
        // delete to do entry
     @RequestMapping(value = "/delete-todo", method= RequestMethod.GET) 
     public String deleteToDo(ModelMap model, @RequestParam int id) { 
         service.deleteTodo(id);
         model.clear();
         return "redirect:/list-todo"; }
     
     
}
```

My JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ include file = "common/header.jspf" %>
<%@ include file = "common/nav.jspf" %>
    <div class="container">
        <H1>Update your task!</H1>
    
        <form:form method="POST" commandName="todo">
            <!-- Carry on the id value  -->
            <form:hidden path = "id"/>
    <form:hidden path = "user"/>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <form:label path="description">Description:</form:label>
        
                <form:input path="description" type="text" class="form-control"
                    required="required" />
                <form:errors path="description" cssClass="text-warning" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <form:label path="targetDate">Target Date</form:label>
                <form:input path="targetDate" type="text" class="form-control"
                    required="required" />  
                <form:errors path="targetDate" cssClass="text-warning" />

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group"> 
                <form:radiobutton path="completion" value="true" />
                <form:radiobutton path="completion" value="false" />
            </fieldset>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit Update</button>
        </form:form>
<spring:hasBindErrors htmlEscape="true" name="todo">
    <c:if test="${errors.errorCount gt 0}">
    <h4>The error list :</h4>
    <font color="red">
      <c:forEach items="${errors.allErrors}" var="error">
        <spring:message code="${error.code}"
                        arguments="${error.arguments}"
                        text="${error.defaultMessage}"/><br/>
      </c:forEach>
    </font>
  </c:if>   
</spring:hasBindErrors>
    </div>
<%@ include file = "common/footer.jspf" %>
```

EDIT: bindingresult throws this

```
ERROR[Field error in object 'todo' on field 'targetDate': rejected value [Tue Jan 05 00:00:00 SGT 2021]; codes [typeMismatch.todo.targetDate,typeMismatch.targetDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [todo.targetDate,targetDate]; arguments []; default message [targetDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'targetDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value 'Tue Jan 05 00:00:00 SGT 2021'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]]
```

Comment: No exception because (result.hasErrors()) and i'm not sure how to get error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jsp you submit the form to "todo", not "update-todo". It would be nice to see your ToDo bean. Also: result.getAllErrors().

Comment: Just change the input type to "date".